# Realloc not copying old values

Tags: c, ascii, realloc

When doing my project I've came across to a problem. I It seems like `realloc` is not copying all data from original array. This is what I'm dealing with (code still missing error checking, I know) :

```
char ** dictionary = (char**) malloc(512  * sizeof(char*));

for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    dictionary[i] = (char*) malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
    sprintf(dictionary[i], "%c", i);
}

char * character = dictionary[129];

char ** new_dictionary = realloc(dictionary, 1024);
dictionary = new_dictionary;

char * character2 = dictionary[129];
```

I first create a array of pointers to char pointers. Then I create pointer to array of chars for each byte and assign byte value. Values of `character` and `character2` differ. Why? I've checked for lower and higer indexes (few samples) and the values remains the same. Does  this have something to do with that I'm trying to `realloc` char pointers not just pure data?

Comment: Not all values in the range `0` to `255` will be printable characters. Also note that ASCII is only a 7-bit encoding, with values up to (and including) `127`. Anything above that will be implementation-specific.

Comment: Also, in your "real" code, do you have error checking? Both `malloc` and `realloc` can fail without warning.

Comment: And you really [should not cast the result of `malloc` (or `realloc` or any other function returning `void *`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858).

Comment: What does "not all data" mean? How much is available? BTW: `realloc` will probably not copy anything as you are shrinking the memory. Inititally you allocate space for 512 pointers and then resize to 1024 bytes. On a 64bit system that is only sufficient for 128 pointers and `dictionary[129]` will be out of bounds then.

Comment: By the way, how do you check if `character` and `character2` (which are not good names by the way, as they aren't really characters)? Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre], or if you use a debugger then tell us that in the question itself.

Comment: @Gerhardh That out of bounds condition is probably the culprit. Assuming the OP really wanted to *increase* the memory, perhaps you should post an answer with the details from the comment and show how to increase properly?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Initially I wasn't sure if that would qualify as typo. But now it's an answer. ;)

Comment: @Gerhardh Yeah, my god how did I do such a simple mistake. I guess it just was not adding up since every higher index I tried did work.  Imma close this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you are trying to do.
I assume you want to increase the memory and expect `realloc` to copy the content of the initial memory block.

This will not happen in your code:

```c
char ** dictionary = (char**) malloc(512  * sizeof(char*));
...
char ** new_dictionary = realloc(dictionary, 1024);
dictionary = new_dictionary;

char * character2 = dictionary[129];
```

You are actually shrinking your memory size.
Initialliy you reserve memory for 512 *pointers*. Then you resize to 1024 *bytes*. On a 64 bit system that will only be sufficient for 128 pointers.
As a result, `dictionary[129]` is an out of bounds access.

You probably wanted to resize this way:

```c
realloc(dictionary, 1024 * sizeof *dictionary)
```